# установка zsh в ubuntu server

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

необходимо установить oh-my-zsh на ubuntu server. при выполнении команды `sudo apt-get install zsh` пишет  "не удалось найти пакет zsh". другие пакеты тоже через одного устанавливает. можно ли это сделать? и если да то как?
при выполнении команды `echo $0` показывает только bash

Comment: 1. список пакетов обновляете перед установкой? 2. приложите к вопросу вывод `$ tail -n 100 /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*.list}; cat /etc/*release*`

Comment: 3. какая версия Ubuntu?

Comment: @Hellseher @alexanderbarakin ubuntu 16.04. настроек инета не было оказывается. тупанул. пишу  `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`. запускается файл настроек. там пишу <br/> `iface enp1s0 inet static <br/> address 192.168.95.225 <br/> netmask 255.255.255.0 <br/> gateway 192.168.95.1 <br/> dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.95.1<br/> auto enp1s0` <br/> enp1s0 посмотрел через команду sudo lshw -C network  в графе logical_name.